# Grid cell has multiple rows and each row can be editiable

Tags: grid, inline-editing

I would like to have build a grid, each cell can have multiple rows and each of the row can be editable. and each cell can be right click on the cell also. I am thinking jquery for the choice of grid. But there are a few work need to be done. Are there any other grid out there very close to what I require and not much of work require would be good. Thanks for answering my qestions

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid has the functionality you have specified.
See the online documentation: 
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing